# default argument overwriting c++

Tags: c++

i have a problem that when you make an object and enter arguments into it, for example `foo f(0,5,0);` the objects default arguments take over and replace the arguemnts i entered when making the object. I hope this makes sense and feel free to leave a comment if I need to change something.

code:
yo.h

```
class yo {
public:
    yo(int Y=0, int Speed=1);

    void move(); //where i use the varibles
    int getx() { return x;}

private:

    int x, y, speed;
};
```

yo.cpp

```
yo::yo(int Y, int Speed)
    :x(1280), y(Y), speed(Speed)
{}

void yo::move() {
    x -= speed;
    std::cout << speed << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
std::vector<yo> yos(20);

void spawnYos() {
    yo e(340, 5);
    yos.push_back(e);
}

int main() {
    spawnYos();
    while(true) {
        for (int i = 0; i != yos.size(); i++) {
            yos.at(i).move();
            if (yos.at(i).getx() < 0 or yos.at(i).getx() > 1290) {
                yos.erase(yos.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this `yos.at(i).move();` prints the default argument (`1`) while I spesificly said `yo e(340, 5);` . it should be printing 5.

Comment: *"default arguments take over and replace the arguemnts i entered"* How do you know this if your program doesn't print anything?

Comment: Unrelated, but setting everything to `NULL` in `~yo` isn't doing what you think it is.  You don't need a destructor in this example at all.

Comment: I have tested it many different way and each way it always came out as the default argument. I just didn't include the testing part in the code.

Comment: Oh thanks @StephenNewell makes sense now that I think about it

Comment: Without your testing code, we can't verify the bug.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *"have tested it many different way"* Can you please show us the code that prints something, tell what it prints, and what you expected it to print?

Comment: `x = NULL;`??? `x` is an `int`; code snippets like these are exactly why you should go with `nullptr` instead of the ansi c macro `NULL`. The compiler would have told you in that case that you're trying to so something weird there.

Comment: You told it to make 20 default yos. instead do `yos.emplace_back(340,5)` 20 times.

Comment: Btw: `std::vector<yo> yos(20);` does create a vector that contains 20 default initialized `yo` objects which in contrast to the 21st element you insert do use the default params of the constructor.

Comment: Are you aware that `std::vector<yo> yos(20)` creates a vector with 20 default constructed elements in it and `spawnYos` would add an additional one so it would have 21 element? So if you check the fist 20 elements they will have the default values.

Comment: The program as shown does not compile, `enemies` is not declared. Please post a [mcve]. Ensure minimality: you don't need 20 elements in a vector or an infinite loop to demonstrate a problem.

Comment: oops was supposed to delete those my fault guys

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You start by default constructing 20 `yo`s:

```
std::vector<yo> yos(20);
```

All 20 have `x = 1280`, `y = 0` and `speed = 1`.

You then add one extra with the value you want:

```
yo e(340, 5);
yos.push_back(e);
```

You now have 20 default constructed `yo`s + 1 with `x = 1280`, `y = 340` and `speed = 5`.

From your description, I think you want 20 `yo(340, 5)` elements. You can create those by adding a `yo` to copy when constructing your `vector` of 20 elements:

```
std::vector<yo> yos(20, {340, 5});
```

`spawnYos()` can now be removed and the declaration of `yos` can be moved into `main` instead of having a global variable.

Also correct the stepping of `i` in your `for` loop. If you `erase` an element, you will miss the `i != yos.size()` condition *or* miss to `move()` the next element after the `erase`d if you do `i++` unconditionally.

Example:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<yo> yos(20, {340, 5});

    while(true) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != yos.size();) {
            yos.at(i).move();
            if (yos.at(i).getx() < 0 or yos.at(i).getx() > 1290) {
                yos.erase(yos.begin() + i);
            } else {
                ++i; // only step i if you don't remove an element
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This program has no way of terminating normally. Such programs have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) so you need to give the program some clean way of exiting. I suggest changing

```
while(true) { ... }
```

to

```
while(!yos.empty()) { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't won't work for me because if I add say, ```yo e(100,60)``` it still is automatics corrected to y = 340 and speed = 5. Nice try.

Comment: @Kenbo No it wont. You are looking at the wrong element.

Comment: @Kenbo [Look at this example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y84v7f36x) and you'll see that `yo e(100,60)` is not _corrected_ to y = 340 and speed = 5.

Comment: you aren't putting the e object in the yos vector!

Comment: with what i am doing, you have to put it in the vector or it won't get updated.

Comment: @Kenbo If I `push_back` `e` into the `vector` it will be copied there and it will have exactly the same values as the original `e`. It will be the last element in the `vector`. - Look at this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oMqsMqGY7) where I call `move()` on the last element in the `vector`. Also look at the loop that follows. You'll see twenty `5`:s and one `60`.

Comment: well no but i figured it out somehow and it is working for my game. Thanks a lot tho bro!

Comment: @Kenbo You are welcome. Since you figured it out, please post an answer to your own question. Otherwise other people coming here with a similar problem won't have a clue how to solve their problem.

Comment: well I can't because, the answer wasn't related to this question at all. I figured it a way use other code and stuff

Comment: @Kenbo "_the answer wasn't related to this question at all, I figured it a way use other code and stuff_" - Then please delete the question.

Comment: i cant becuase it saying people have put effort into this

Comment: @Kenbo Ok, then you could reformulate the question to the question you meant to ask so that the question becomes answerable